# Sample code not doing as expected

Tags: java

Here is the algorithm (not working) Please let me know where the error is

Thanks

```
private void checkSouth(Location point, int player) {
        //Loop through everything south
        boolean isthereAnOppositePlayer=false;

        int oppositePlayer=0;
        //Set opposite player
        if (player==1) {
            oppositePlayer=2;
        }else{
            oppositePlayer=1;
        }

        for (int i = point.getVertical(); i < 8; i++) {

            //Create a location point with the current location being compared
            MyLocation locationBeingChecked= new MyLocation();
            locationBeingChecked.setHorizontal(point.getHorizontal());
            locationBeingChecked.setVertical(i);

            int value = board[locationBeingChecked.getVertical()][locationBeingChecked.getHorizontal()];

            //If the first checked is the opposite player
            if (value==oppositePlayer) {
                //Then potential to evaluate more
                isthereAnOppositePlayer=true;
            }
            //If it isn't an opposite player, then break
            if(!isthereAnOppositePlayer && value!=0){
                break;
            }

            //If another of the player's piece found or 0, then end
            if (isthereAnOppositePlayer && value==player || isthereAnOppositePlayer && value==0) {
                break;
                //end   
            }

            //Add to number of players to flip
            if(isthereAnOppositePlayer && value==oppositePlayer && value!=0){
                //add to array
                addToPiecesToTurn(locationBeingChecked);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's not working about it?

Comment: This isn't much to work off of. Maybe provide an error report or where the problem is occurring.

Comment: its not finding some pieces, or flipping over ones that shouldn't be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the locations that got rotated back to the other player are the exact same as those rotated during the first move.  I would guess that the array being populated by `addToPiecesToTurn` is perhaps not being cleared out between each move, so all the previous locations are still in there.

If you are storing the pieces to be turned in an `ArrayList`, you can use the [`clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) method to erase the contents of the collection between each turn.

---

Another possible problem is that you are checking for the opposite player, and then instantly beginning to populate `addToPiecesToTurn`.  However, the pieces in that direction are not necessarily valid to be rotated unless they are "sandwiched" in by a second location containing the current player's piece.  I don't think your code is properly checking for that case; when that happens, you'll want to somehow skip flipping those pieces to the other player, such as clearing out the array of `piecesToTurn`.

---

**Edit**: Looking at your current solution where you are implementing every direction separately, you are going to have a lot of duplicated code.  If you think about what it means to walk along a certain direction, you can think of it as adjusting the x/y value by a "step" amount.  The step amount could be `-1` for backwards, `0` for no move, or `1` for forwards.  Then you could create a single method that handles all directions without duplicating the logic:

```
private void checkDirection(Location point, int player, int yStep, int xStep) {
    int x = point.getHorizontal() + xStep;
    int y = point.getVertical() + yStep;

    MyLocation locationBeingChecked = new MyLocation();
    locationBeingChecked.setHorizontal(x);
    locationBeingChecked.setVertical(y);

    while (isValid(locationBeingChecked)) {
        // do the logic here

        x += xStep;
        y += yStep;

        locationBeingChecked = new MyLocation();
        locationBeingChecked.setHorizontal(x);
        locationBeingChecked.setVertical(y);
    }
}
```

You would need to implement `isValid` to check that the location is valid, i.e., in the board.  Then you could call this method for each direction:

```
// north
checkDirection(curPoint, curPlayer, -1, 0);
// north-east
checkDirection(curPoint, curPlayer, -1, 1);
// east
checkDirection(curPoint, curPlayer, 0, 1);
// etc
```

Comment: Yes that helped, but now piece at 3,2 flips (3,3 stopped flipping) (thank you), any clue what else could be causing that other flip?

Comment: Ok, How would I fix the bottom suggestion?

Comment: Does your code only implement `checkSouth` so far, or are you just not showing the rest of them?

Comment: it does 8 direction south north, northeast, etc... for debugging I am only using NSEW

Comment: It depends on how you implement the flipping of the pieces.  Do you accumulate all of them throughout all the directions and then flip them at the end?  If you would for instance flip the tiles and clear out the pieces to turn between every checked direction, then you could simply clear it out if you don't find a "sandwiching" piece on the other end - so that particular direction is "skipped".  It won't work if you are accumulating all of them, because clearing out the array may accidentally remove some valid entries.

Comment: I got through all eight directions, accumulate, then flip at once (updated move two to how it looks now)

Comment: OK.  You'll either need to put them in a temporary array that you add all to pieces to turn only once you find the closing piece; or you'll need to somehow "check ahead" that there is a piece of the current player to sandwich in the other players' pieces before you add them to the array.

Comment: I've added an Edit with a suggestion on how to simplify your code for each direction so you don't have a lot of copy-paste.  It is a good habit as you are developing your programming skill to think of ways to prevent duplication of logic.  It helps in the long run for better code maintenance.

Comment: wow thats awesome, I will test out and see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of problem that is ripe for some unit testing. You could very easily set up a board, play a move, and validate the answer, and the test results would give plenty of insight into where your expectations and reality diverge.

Answer (score 0):

why didn't you use a 2d array ?

each cell would contain an enum : EMPTY, PLAYER_1, PLAYER_2 .

then, in order to go over the cells, you simply use loops for each direction.

for example, upon clicking on a cell , checking to the right would be:

```
for(int x=pressedLocation.x+1;x<cells[pressedLocation.y].length;++x)
  {
  Cell cell=cells[pressedLocation.y][x];
  if(cell==EMPTY||cell==currentPlayerCell)
    break;
  cells[pressedLocation.y][x]=currentPlayerCell;
  }
```

checking from top to bottom would be:

```
for(int y=pressedLocation.y+1;y<cells.length;++y)
  {
  Cell cell=cells[y][pressedLocation.x];
  if(cell==EMPTY||cell==currentPlayerCell)
    break;
  cells[y][pressedLocation.x]=currentPlayerCell;
  }
```

Comment: As opposed to `int value = board[locationBeingChecked.getVertical()][locationBeingChecked.getHorizontal()];`?

Comment: this is a two d array... board[][]

Comment: anyway, i've posted the solution in the shorter way. hope you can adjust it for your needs.